# how to exploit the kernel vulnerability

Tags: security

I am studying kernel vulnerabilities.

I searched for kernel vulnerabilities, and most of them are just talk about privilege escalation.

Can the kernel vulnerability run shellcode?

For example, can not you get a shell by injecting remote remote code like system(/bin/sh)?

Thanks.

Comment: It's way too broad this way unfortunately. There are different vulnerabilities in software, including OS kernels. Depending on the vulnerability, it can or cannot be exploited, and it can allow different things under different circumstances if exploitable.

Comment: @GaborLengyel Thank you for your feedback.
Can you give me a link to a related case?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)